# High quantum harmonic eigenfunctions?

Tags: physics

How to obtain high quantum harmonic eigenfunctions? Everything works until, let say 65th eigenfunction, but for higher eigenfunctions values are too high.
My code

```
NoH = Table[1/Sqrt[2^n n!] Pi^(-1/4), {n, 0, ns - 1}];
phi[x_] = Table[NoH[[i]] HermiteH[i - 1, x] Exp[-x^2/2], {i, ns}];
```

NoH are normalization factors, phi[x] are eigenfunctions.

Best regards.

Comment: I don't see what the problem is. Could you add detail? Also, why does it matter than they're eigenfunction to the QHO? this is irrelevant.

Comment: Chances are that you get into trouble using machine precision, since for higher eigenfunctions massive cancellations of large quantities lead to accumulation of errors. Try to increase the precision, and, generally, work at fixed precision - then Mathematica will track the precision for you and you will see how reliable your results are.

Comment: Also, it would be best to include complete self-contained examples, so that we don't have to guess what your real problem is.

Comment: These are highly oscillating functions, especially for large i. If you will try to plot, let say 100th eigenfunction, you would see that values are too high, there are very high peeks.

Comment: But that's what I mean: those oscillations are constructed by a high-degree polynomial plus the exponent - so the right oscillatory behavior is a result of non-trivial cancellation of individual terms in the polynomials (and exponent), which are quite large for large `x`.

Comment: thanks, you have right. so how to increase the precision in this case?

Comment: At some point, you may actually be better off, in terms of computations, by using the WKB - approximated functions, for large values of the quantum number (where WKB works quite well).

Comment: You have to compute the functions on numbers of that precision. So, if you want to use `Plot`, you may need some tricks like `N[Rationalize[x],30]` instead of `x` in your function (or whatever precision you want to set). This will however slow things down considerably. You could also use interpolation on some fine grid, and then plot that interpolated function, I guess.

Comment: Plot doesn't work with this trick, however ListLinePlot does. WKB is also interesting :)  Thanks!

Comment: Also another easy way is to add the `WorkingPrecision -> 30` (which precision is required depends on the order of your polynomials) option when calling `Plot`. This will instruct `Plot` to use higher precision when evaluating your functions, which will avoid the numeric cancellations Leonid mentioned.

Comment: E.g. for `ns=100` try `Plot[Evaluate@Last@phi[x], {x, -20, 20}, WorkingPrecision -> 30]` to plot the highest order Eigenfunction.

Answer (score 4):

It's very easy to get around the numerical problem:

Instead of asking *Mathematica* to generate a list of 100 or so function values at every value of the independent variable `x`, just define the functions individually for each index:

```
phi1[n_][x_] := 1/Sqrt[2^n n!] Pi^(-1/4) HermiteH[n - 1, x] Exp[-x^2/2]

Plot[phi1[99][x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot]

```
Plot[phi1[200][x], {x, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: plot200]

In this way, the numerical accuracy is tracked individually for each index, not for the whole table.

**Edit: what about tables of functions?**

From the fact that you defined a table, one can guess that you wanted to plot a set of these functions in a single plot. In that case, you again have the numerical stability problem, so it's best to separate the individual plots and combine them with `Show`:

```
Show[Table[
  Plot[phi1[n][x], {x, 0, 21}, PlotRange -> All, 
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[1][n]], {n, 100, 150, 10}]]
```

[image: Show]

Here, I used `ColorData[1]` as the default color scheme that you also get when plotting a table of functions. The `PlotRange` is determined by the first of the plots in `Show` (but since I chose `All` it will make everything fit into the frame), but you can change that explicitly if needed.

I had some custom style options set when making these plots, so yours will have no frame and a different font by default...

Comment: Something I don't understand: even with the function defined this way, the problem arises if the `x` in the expression isn't local to the `Plot`. e.g. `expr = phi1[99][x]; Plot[expr, {x,0,20}]` In fact the OP's code works if `phi` is defined using `SetDelayed`.

Comment: @SimonWoods It looks like the numerical errors appear whenever the high-degree polynomials are passed to `Plot` in expanded form. When `Plot` sees that they are `HermiteH` polynomials, it does the right thing. But since we can't look inside the `Plot` code, that's all I can hypothesize.

Comment: Interesting that when we define phi as a function of two variables it works, and when we define it as a table it doesn't. Thank you.